# why my scrapy didnt scrapy anything?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my spider.
After I execute the spider,nothing appear.
I don't know why it is blank.
I feel the problem is yield and return,but i don't know how to change it.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Selector
from CSDNBlog1.items import Csdnblog1Item

class CSDNBlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='CSDNBlog1'
    download_delay=1
    allowed_domains=['blog.csdn.net']
    starts_urls=['http://blog.csdn.net/u012150179/article/details/117490171']

    def parse(self,response):
        sel=Selector(response)
        items=[]
        item=Csdnblog1Item()
        aricle_url=str(response.url)
        article_name=sel.xpath('//div[@id="article_details"]/div/h1/span/a/text()').extract()

        item['article_name']=[n.encode('utf-8') for n in article_name]
        item['article_url']=article_url.encode('utf-8')
        yield item


        urls=sel.xpath('//li[@class="next_article"]/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
            url="http://blog.csdn.net"+url
            print(url)
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

This is my spider situations,it did nothing.

```
2017-02-06 15:35:46 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-02-06 15:35:46 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped     0
```

Comment: It mean that I dont't know why I scrapy this website,but nothing.

Comment: why my scrapy didnt scrapy anything?

Comment: You should use `start_urls`, not `starts_urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start_url is no more working, and the yield statement is in a wrong position.
Please try with the following code:

```
import scrapy
from CSDNBlog1.items import Csdnblog1Item
from scrapy import Selector

class Csdnblog1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "CSDNBlog2"
    download_delay=1
    allowed_domains = ["http://blog.csdn.net/"]
    start_urls = ['http://blog.csdn.net/u012150179/article/details/37306629/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item=Csdnblog1Item()
        sel=Selector(response)
        item['project'] = self.settings.get('BOT_NAME')

        article_url=str(response.url)
        article_name=sel.xpath('//div[@id="article_details"]/div/h1/span/a/text()').extract()

        item['article_name']=[n.encode('utf-8') for n in article_name]
        item['article_url']=article_url.encode('utf-8')

        urls=sel.xpath('//li[@class="next_article"]/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
            url="http://blog.csdn.net"+url
            print(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)

    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: fetch('http://blog.csdn.net/u012150179/article/details/117490171')
2017-02-06 16:41:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://blog.csdn.net/error/404.html?from=http%3a%2f%2fblog.csdn.net%2fu012150179%2farticle%2fdetails%2f117490171> from <GET http://blog.csdn.net/u012150179/article/details/117490171>
2017-02-06 16:41:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://blog.csdn.net/error/404.html?from=http%3a%2f%2fblog.csdn.net%2fu012150179%2farticle%2fdetails%2f117490171> (referer: None)
```

Make sure you get right `start_url`